# RuntimeException Performing pause of activity that is not resumed without explicit call of lifecycle methods

Tags: android, android-activity

I have problem with this exception, but I dont know where is problem. This exception is thrown only on Android 5 (Android 6 is ok). Do you know any general source of this problems? How is possible that onPause is called before onResume is finished? Sharing of activity content is not good way. I have complex activity.

Can cause problems this code?

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Or this:

```
 @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    hideToast();
  }
```

I call method hideToast from onPause. I use Singleton class for managing of toasts.

Comment: are you launching or finishing or recreating activity from `onResume` method?

Comment: Not. I use activity in fullscreen mode. Exception occurs when I what to switch off wifi connection.

Comment: @lubo can you update your question with code of complete class?